# getting ProcessId within Python code

Tags: python

I am in Windows and Suppose I have a main python code that calls python interpreter in command line to execute another python script ,say test.py .

So test.py is executed as a new process.How can I find the processId for this porcess in Python ?

**Update:**

To be more specific , we have os.getpid() in os module. It returns the current process id.

If I have a main program that runs Python interpreter to run another script , how can I get the process Id for that executing script ?

Comment: If you know you will only have one instance of test.py running at a time, you could always just write at the beginning to a test.pid file which only contains the process Id of the running test.py

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you used subprocess to spawn the shell, you can find the process ID in the [`pid`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.pid) property:

```
sp = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'script.py'])
print('PID is ' + str(sp.pid))
```

If you used multiprocessing, use *its* [pid](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.pid) property:

```
p = multiprocessing.Process()
p.start()
# Some time later ...
print('PID is ' + str(p.pid))
```

Answer (score 7):

It all depends on how you're launching the second process.

If you're using `os.system` or similar, that call won't report back anything useful about the child process's pid. One option is to have your 2nd script communicate the result of `os.getpid()` back to the original process via stdin/stdout, or write it to a predetermined file location. Another alternative is to use the third-party [`psutil`](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) library to figure out which process it is.

On the other hand, if you're using the `subprocess` module to launch the script, the resulting "popen" object has an attribute [`popen.pid`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.pid) which will give you the process id.

Answer (score 0):

You will receive the process ID of the newly created process when you create it. At least, you will if you used fork() (Unix), posix_spawn(), CreateProcess() (Win32) or probably any other reasonable mechanism to create it.

If you invoke the "python" binary, the python PID will be the PID of this binary that you invoke. It's not going to create another subprocess for itself (Unless your python code does that).

Comment: Mark I don't get your last statement.Would you elaborate on that please?

Suppose pseudocode is like this:  

main.py  

commandLine(Python testScript.py) //Non-Blocking  

you say test.py and Python Interpreter both will have the same   process Id? This makes sense.

Comment: May have misunderstood your question; I assumed you were invoking python from some other language. I'm not sure my answer makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is that the process you execute will set a console window title for himself.
And the searching process will enumerate all windows, find the relevant window handle by name and use the handle to find PID.  It works on windows using ctypes.