# Obtaining PID of a shell / python script inside the script itself

Tags: python, bash

How can I obtain the PID of a shell script inside the script itself and pass the same to another script?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? an example of your attempts would be helpful...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting ProcessId within Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250126/getting-processid-within-python-code)

Answer (score 27):

The process ID of the current process can be retrieved with `os.getpid()`.

```
import os

print("This process has the PID", os.getpid())
```

In bash, you can use `$$` to get the PID of the bash instance running the script.

Comment: Ho can i obtain the same for shell script

Comment: @AkhilPSudhakaran, why do you tag the question with python if you're interested in shell scripts? What shell are you using under which platform?

Comment: I need to do the same in both shell and python , ok thanks for your support . I am using "bash"  , could you please advise for the same  [pydev@auto1 Test_Script]$ cat /etc/*-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)

Answer (score 4):

It's years and years later but in UNIX systems $$ is a type of variable for shell PID.

You should try;

```
echo $$
```

Code above returns the PID of the shell you are working at.

And also Python's os library has a method called getpid

```
import os
os.getpid()
```

You can store this variable in temp file in /tmp/anyFile path. And by doing this, other script you mentioned could access this file

Comment: thank you for the response. The question from the OP is to capture the PID and pass it to another script. Not much information is available from the OP so it is difficult to answer.  Can you please elaborate on your answer to help the OP.

Comment: Not the answer-er but:
    <code>
    import os
    scriptPID = os.getpid()
    </code>    
Now you'd need to pass that variable to another script.  This can be done by built-in sockets, or my personal preference is to use ZeroMQ for message passing like this.  If you use the /tmp/anyFile path referenced above, any other script would open the file to find the PID.  But it all depends on how the OP wants to use that PID - and whether they are even still following this old thread.  I'm mostly putting this here in case anyone else comes across it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your says David, I believe that the developer should question whether or not the PID information is sensitive or not. ZeroMQ or something similar would be great use but also can be complex depending on the project. Sincerely.