# how to get spark executor process PID in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

suppose a spark job running in cluster mode launches 3 executors in cluster mode, then how to fetch the process ID (PID) of each of the executor processes in the spark cluster.? **is there any api for this in pyspark.?**

EDIT:
The question is about the executor jvm process ID (PID) not the executor ID. so how to fetch the executor process id using pyspark APIs.?

Comment: the above given link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250126/getting-processid-within-python-code) did not solve my problem.. yet it has been marked as duplicate even though I supplied the EDIT.

Comment: [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions).